# How to Pragmatically Access Click Event Which Toolstrip Also Defined Programmatically

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I defined toolstrip & toolstrip buttons within the form cording. Its working fine. I want to know how to access click event each & every button.

When I'm run the form, ToolStrip enable too. But when I click TooStripButtons it didn't access.

Variable Declaration

```
Dim tsToolStrip As ToolStrip

Dim tsbNew, _
    tsbEdit, _
    tsbDelete, _
    tsbSave, _
    tsbPrint, _
    tsbCancel As ToolStripButton

Dim tssSepe01, _
    tssSepe02, _
    tssSepe03 As ToolStripSeparator
```

Tool Strip Setup

```
Sub ToolStripSetup()
    
        ' ToolStrip Inizializing
        tsToolStrip = New ToolStrip
        ' ToolStrip Seperators Inizializing
        tssSepe01 = New ToolStripSeparator
        tssSepe02 = New ToolStripSeparator
        tssSepe03 = New ToolStripSeparator
        ' ToolStrip Buttons Inizializing
        tsbNew = New ToolStripButton
        tsbEdit = New ToolStripButton
        tsbDelete = New ToolStripButton
        tsbSave = New ToolStripButton
        tsbPrint = New ToolStripButton
        tsbCancel = New ToolStripButton

        With tsbNew
            .Name = "tsbNew"
            .Image = My.Resources.NewFile_16x
            .Text = "&New"
            .DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
            .TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText
            .Enabled = False
        End With

        With tsbEdit
            .Name = "tsbEdit"
            .Image = My.Resources.Edit_16x
            .Text = "&Edit"
            .DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
            .TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText
            .Enabled = False
        End With

        With tsbDelete
            .Name = "tsbDelete"
            .Image = My.Resources.DeleteDatabase_16x
            .Text = "&Delete"
            .DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
            .TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText
            .Enabled = False
        End With

        With tsbSave
            .Name = "tsbSave"
            .Image = My.Resources.Save_16x
            .Text = "&Save"
            .DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
            .TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText
            .Enabled = False
        End With

        With tsbPrint
            .Name = "tsbPrint"
            .Image = My.Resources.Print_16x
            .Text = "&Print"
            .DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
            .TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText
            .Enabled = False
        End With

        With tsbCancel
            .Name = "tsbCancel"
            .Image = My.Resources.action_Cancel_16xLG
            .Text = "&Cancel"
            .DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
            .TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText
        End With

        ' Adding Buttons To ToolStrip
        With tsToolStrip
            .Name = "tsToolStrip"
            .GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden
            .RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.System
            With .Items
                .Add(tsbNew) ' New Button
                .Add(tsbEdit) ' Edit Button
                .Add(tsbDelete) ' Delete Button
                .Add(tssSepe01)
                .Add(tsbSave) ' Save Button
                .Add(tssSepe02)
                .Add(tsbPrint) ' Print Button
                .Add(tssSepe03)
                .Add(tsbCancel) ' Cancel Button
            End With
        End With

        Controls.Add(tsToolStrip)

    
End Sub
```

I above posted my sample code. Can anyone please help me how to do this

Comment: Each button has its own `Click` event so you handle each one individually, because you want each one to do something specific to that button. It's no different to having multiple `Button` controls on a form. You currently have no event handlers so of course nothing happens. I'm not really sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Is it possible that you meant to say "programmatically" rather than "pragmatically" in your title? If that's what you don't know how to do then you could have found it easily enough with a web search using the right word. Do some research on the `AddHandler` statement, which is how you register an event handler for dynamically created objects. That said, if you are using member variables for each button then you can declare them `WithEvents` and then create event handlers using the navigation bar at the top of the code window, using `Handles` clauses.

Comment: I try to add AddHandler but the error shows - Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

Comment: There's obviously no way that you get an error message about `Handles` when you use `AddHandler`. Apart from that, you haven't shown any attempt to use either in your question. Provide ALL the relevant information in the question. No one should have to read your comments - especially when they're nonsense - to understand the question.

Comment: If you are going to try to use `Handles` clauses then I already told you that you need to declare your fields `WithEvents`, so why would you be surprised to get an error message if you don't do that? I didn't make that statement in a previous comment for no reason.

Comment: Oh I miss that. Yes its works fine. Thank You.

Comment: If you're able to - not sure if you need more rep points to do so - you should post an answer and show what you did and accept it, so that it might help others in the future. I think that you'll gain some rep points by doing so too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank For Answer

This is how I done my coding

```
Dim WithEvents tsbNew, _
    tsbEdit, _
    tsbDelete, _
    tsbSave, _
    tsbPrint, _
    tsbCancel As ToolStripButton



Private Sub tsbCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbCancel.Click
    
        FormInizalization()
    
End Sub
```